# How Can I Correctly Use Registry Permissions to Delete a Registry Subkey in C#?

Tags: c#, registry, registrykey

In the Windows Registry I have the subkey `\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\HTMPTK`, which has two values: `Secret Token` and `Token`. I want to delete the two values.

I attempted to use `key.DeleteValue("Secret Token")` (`key` is a `RegistryKey` variable), but I got an `UnauthorizedAccessException`, with the message *Cannot write to the registry key*.

Tinkering around MSDN and Google, to allow the program the access it needs, I found the `RegistryPermission` class, along with some examples as guidance. Thus, I wrote the following code:

```
private bool DeleteTokensFromRegistryEngine()
        {
            RegistryPermission perm = new RegistryPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
            perm.AddPathList(RegistryPermissionAccess.AllAccess, "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\HTMPTK");
            RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("HTMPTK");
            try
            {
                if (key != null)
                {
                    key.DeleteValue("Secret Token"); //the same error message here
                    key.DeleteValue("Token");
                }
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException U)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(U.Message);
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                key.Close();
            }
            return true;
        }
```

The problem did not disappear.

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this problem?

**Later edit**:

1. I double checked to see if I run the program as an Administrator. I do;
2. Nothing suspicious signaled by Windows Defender;
3. If it helps, I can delete the values from Registry Editor;

Comment: Do you run as administrator your debugged program

Comment: Check your anti-virus program's log if you use. it can quarantine your changes

Comment: Edited again my question

Comment: Keys, much like files or maybe better folders, have permission settings. In the registry editor, right click on a key and select "Permissions...". That should give you hint who is allowed to do what on your keys and why your program currently isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was because I was using the wrong `OpenSubKey` ctor. The correct one was:

`OpenSubKey(String, RegistryRights)`

In my case, the subkey should have been opened with:

`RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("HTMPTK",RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubtree);`

However, there is a better way: because I want to delete both values, it's easier if to delete the whole subkey. I applied this method, and the resulting code was:

```
        try
        {
            Registry.CurrentUser.DeleteSubKeyTree("HTMPTK", true);                
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException U)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(U.Message);
            return false;
        }
```